# How to call mini cart in footer in magento?

Tags: magento

I want to call mini cart in footer.
i have to use below code in xml file

```
<reference name="footer">
     <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="footer_cart" template="checkout/cart/topcart.phtml" before="-">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
            <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
        </block>
    </block>
    </reference>
```

or `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('top_cart') ?>` in footer.phtml.
but its not working for me. please give me any idea for do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you name of block is `footer_cart` so

change

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('top_cart') ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_cart') ?>
```

other problem is you are calling the wrong file

change

`<block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="footer_cart" template="checkout/cart/topcart.phtml" before="-">`

to

`<block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="footer_cart" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">`

Comment: I have to added the code in page.xml or footer.phtml.

Comment: anyone please give me idea

Comment: change `<block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="footer_cart" template="checkout/cart/topcart.phtml" before="-">` to `<block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar"  as="footer_cart" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" >`  and i tested this code it is working

Comment: In footer.phtml  you use which code <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('top_cart') ?> or <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_cart') ?>

Comment: <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_cart') ?>  this one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106705/discussion-between-kirmal-brar-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: hello Qaisar..need your help

Comment: tell me how can i help you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980561/how-to-stop-order-processing-of-same-order-once-if-order-status-is-canceled-in-m

Comment: Hi @Qaiser .. need your help 
please have a look to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437526/error-in-configurable-products-on-detail-page

Comment: Hi Qaisar need your help
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120084/how-to-pass-telephone-number-in-paypal-standard

Comment: Hi Qaisar need your  help. are you there

Comment: please check it  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810827/permission-block-error-in-magento

Comment: Hi Qaisar Satti  need your help. please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48800875/error-in-draw-image-on-pdf-using-zend-framework-in-magento2