# How to stop order processing of same order once if order status is canceled in Magento?

Tags: magento

How to stop processing of the same order once the order is cancelled ?
I'm using paypal payment method,While placing the order from paypal if I cancel the order from the paypal gateway (Cancel and return),it set the order status as cancelled and redirected to the cart page, but again if I press browser back button, then it redirects me back to the paypal payment gateway page,and the payment is done succesfully.My order status history shows as **Pending Payment**,**Canceled**,**Order Processing**,**Preparing for delivery**.

How can I stop this?

I tried to update the order status using event and observer, but still I unable to stop this processing.

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getPayment()->getOrder();
$order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getEntityId());
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true);
$order->setStatus("canceled");
$order->save();
```

Comment: I got exactly the same problem with WooCommerce for Wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think problem with you status is change but the state is not changing try below code..

```
              $order->setData('state', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED); 
              $order->setStatus("canceled");
              $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('', false);
              $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
              $order->save();
```

Comment: Status is changing,even my status is also changing but again its processing.
my history status shows as 

'Pending Payment',
'Canceled',
'Canceled' (this one is updating from my event observer file)
'Order Processing',
'Preparing for delivery'

Comment: kindly disabled you cache and check again

Comment: is their any other way to do ?

Comment: which event you are doing that?

Comment: add this `$order->setActionFlag(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::ACTION_FLAG_CANCEL, true);`

Comment: <sales_order_payment_cancel>

Comment: is there any way to expire the paypal when browser back button or through any exception error
through script, i can block the back button for the cart page.but i need to do with php ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110824/discussion-between-kirmal-brar-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: Hello Qaisar, do you have any idea about this problem? have a look please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435778/order-status-not-changed-after-ship-in-magento

Comment: Hi Qaisar Satti , I need yours help for  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215032/magento-2-how-to-get-product-attributes-in-my-module-block-function-which-are