# Order Status not changed after Ship in Magento

Tags: magento

I have a few orders,they will not go to ‘complete’ status after clicking ship and submitting the ship it remain as processing.

I'm using the paypal payment method,its generating the both invoice and shipment pdf, but status remains processing

Also i have checked the  order statuses in system -> Order Statuses , 
complete [Complete] state is only assigned to complete.

Strange problem

```
<events>
    <sales_order_save_after>
        <observers>
            <auto_invoice_order>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>custom_Orderhook_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>implementOrderStatus</method>
            </auto_invoice_order>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_save_after>
</events>
```

I used 'sales_order_save_after' event to debug the order status,but still didn’t able to debug the problem

```
public function canShip()
{
    if ($this->canUnhold() || $this->isPaymentReview()) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->getIsVirtual() || $this->isCanceled()) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->getActionFlag(self::ACTION_FLAG_SHIP) === false) {
        return false;
    }

    foreach ($this->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->getQtyToShip()>0 && !$item->getIsVirtual()
            && !$item->getLockedDoShip())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

canShip() is updating the shipment,but the status still remains as 'Processing'

Does anyone know how this can happen,and how to fix this ?

thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: ok, but do you have any solution for this question?