# Error in configurable products on detail page?

Tags: magento

I am working on Magento. There is an error on my product detail page.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable/Price.php on line 86

But this error is not for all products, it's in some cases. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: I am getting `502 Bad Gateway` on that screenshot, but that could just be my network. Does it fail for anyone else?

Comment: I'm assuming the link was dead, and have removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have a problem in configuration of price attribute (that should be `cost`). Make sure what it attribute used for all types of product.

Comment: Thanks Victor , i debug the error , its in configurable attributes. All attribute fileds are empty which are used in products.