# permission_block error in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.7

I have to installed Magento patches `SUPEE 6788`, after that content on home page is missing, when i add blocks `system->permission-> block` it generate error

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'exclusiv_c523.permission_block' doesn't exist

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table `permission_block` should be created as part of the upgrade of `Mage_Admin` from version 1.6.1.1 to 1.6.1.2.  You can verify that the setup/upgrade scripts succeeded by checking the `version` and `data_version` fields in the `core_resource` table:

```
select * from core_resource where code = 'admin_setup';
```

Both values should show version 1.6.1.2, if either of them do not have this value then it's likely that the upgrade failed.

Comment: admin_setup table have value, then what i can do now.

Comment: what is the value of the field `version` and `data_version` ?

Comment: value is 1.6.1.2 for both

Comment: update the `core_resource` record to say that admin_setup is version 1.6.1.1, clear the cache, and reload the homepage again

Comment: Please provide this as an answer and ask the questioner to accept it, it worked perfectly for me.