# Error in Draw image on PDF using Zend Framework in Magento2

Tags: zend-framework, magento2

I am working on create a catalog PDF in Magento-2 using Zend Framework. My code is here to print catalog image on PDF.

```
foreach ($collection as $product) 
    {
    $image = $product->getImage();
    $path =  $mediaUrl."catalog/product".$image;
    $imagef = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($path);
    // write image to page
    $page->drawImage($imagef, 50, 50, 400, 400);
    }
```

But it did not work for me.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.